# Arduino IDE showing ESP32 Sketch too big. Out of space How to fix it

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth, wifi, esp32

I wrote a small program for ESP32 to show time, date, and crypto price in an OLED display. it also has the option to change watch phases through Bluetooth serial. It compiled successfully without any syntax errors. But it is showing  the following error message

> Sketch too big; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on
> reducing it. Sketch uses 1508690 bytes (115%) of program storage
> space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes. Global variables use 52728 bytes
> (16%) of dynamic memory, leaving 274952 bytes for local variables.
> Maximum is 327680 bytes. text section exceeds available space in board
>
> Compilation error: text section exceeds available space in board

I figured out that "BluetoothSerial.h" and  <WiFi.h> take so much space. How can I fix this

And I am using the esp32 firebeetle. partition scheme option not available to add more space

```
#include <ThreeWire.h>  
#include <RtcDS1302.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SH110X.h>
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "Nokia";
const char* password = "12345678q";

ThreeWire myWire(4,5,2); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
#define i2c_Address 0x3c //initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C Typically eBay OLED's
#define OLED_RESET -1   //   QT-PY / XIAO
Adafruit_SH1106G display = Adafruit_SH1106G(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
char datestring[20];
char Blu_Rec_Data ='f'; //full
char last_Rec_Data ='f';
void setup () 
{
delay(250); // wait for the OLED to power up

 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 SerialBT.print("Connecting to WiFi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)                                        //Connect to the WiFi network
  {
    delay(500);
    SerialBT.print(".");
  } 

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    display.print("Connected");
  }
   display.begin(i2c_Address, true); // Address 0x3C default  
  
    SerialBT.begin("SMART MIRROR");    
    

    Rtc.Begin();

    RtcDateTime compiled = RtcDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);

    // Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);    
    display.println();

    if (!Rtc.IsDateTimeValid()) 
    {
        display.println("RTC lost confidence in the DateTime!");
    }

    if (Rtc.GetIsWriteProtected())
    {
        display.println("RTC was write protected, enabling writing now");
        Rtc.SetIsWriteProtected(false);
    }

    if (!Rtc.GetIsRunning())
    {
        display.println("RTC was not actively running, starting now");
        Rtc.SetIsRunning(true);
    }

    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    if (now < compiled) 
    {
        display.println("RTC is older than compile time!  (Updating DateTime)");
    }
    else if (now > compiled) 
    {
        display.println("RTC is newer than compile time. (this is expected)");
    }
    else if (now == compiled) 
    {
        display.println("RTC is the same as compile time! (not expected but all is fine)");
    }

if(!display.begin(i2c_Address))
{
display.println(F("SH110X allocation failed"));
  
for(;;);}   

delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(SH110X_WHITE);
  display.setCursor(2, 2);
  display.println("starting...");
  display.display(); 
}


void loop () 
{
    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    TheDisplay(now);
    //printDateTime(now);
    display.println();

    if (!now.IsValid())
    {
        display.println("RTC lost confidence in the DateTime!");
    }
    
    if (SerialBT.available()) 
    {
      Blu_Rec_Data = SerialBT.read();
    }
    if(Blu_Rec_Data == 'f' ||Blu_Rec_Data =='d' ||Blu_Rec_Data =='s' ||Blu_Rec_Data =='t')
    {
      last_Rec_Data = Blu_Rec_Data;
    }        
}

void TheDisplay(const RtcDateTime& dt)
{
  if (last_Rec_Data =='f')
  {
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setCursor(0,2);
    display.setTextSize(2.9);  
    display.print(dt.Hour());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Minute());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Second());


    display.setCursor(8,30);
    display.setTextSize(1); 
    display.print("Date: ");
    display.print(dt.Day());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Month());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Year());
    display.print(" ");
    
    display.display();
  }
  if(last_Rec_Data == 'd')
  {
    display.clearDisplay();    
    display.setCursor(0,2);
    display.setTextSize(2.9); 
    display.print("Date: ");
    display.print(dt.Day());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Month());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Year());
    display.print(" ");
    
    display.display();
  } 
  if(last_Rec_Data == 's') 
  {
    HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("https://api.wazirx.com/sapi/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=shibinr");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    String payload = http.getString();
    //display.println(payload);
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
    if (error) {
      display.println("Error: ");

      // handle error
    } else {
      
      String lastPrice = doc["lastPrice"].as<String>();
      float bidPrice = doc["bidPrice"];
      float askPrice = doc["askPrice"];
      display.println(lastPrice); 
      display.display();     
    }
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
  http.end();  
  delay(1000); // delay for 1 minute
  display.println("Delayed");
  display.display();
  }
  if(last_Rec_Data == 't')
  {
     display.clearDisplay();
    display.setCursor(0,2);
    display.setTextSize(2.9);  
    // display.print(" Time: ");
    display.print(dt.Hour());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Minute());
    display.print(":");
    display.print(dt.Second());
    display.display();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Use compiler optimizations or discard functions you do not need. GCC can optimize for size.

Comment: google esp32.upload.maximum_size

Comment: what Partition Scheme did you select in Tools menu?

Comment: @Juraj Partition Scheme option is not available for the esp32 firebeetle.

Comment: If all you want from the received json object are  "lastPrice", "bidPrice" and "askPrice", I would suggest to drop the ArduinoJson library and do the parsing of JSON string yourself. If all you display on the Oled are text, consider replacing Adafruit display libraries (and its dependencies) with something much lightweight like SSD1306ASCII library (which also support SH110x-based display). Adafruit display library is bloated with hidden dependency.

Comment: Compiling with compiler optimizations (like `-O2` or `-O3`) can often reduce the size of your executable - as can enabling Link Time Optimization (`-flto`). Also, if you are enabling debug symbols (`-g` which are often useful while debugging) then turning those off can also result in a smaller binary.